# Django Tastypie atomic operation

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am using Django 1.7.3 as my framework and Tastypie 0.11.1 as rest api library.
I have a basic model with name field and an api for creating this model.

My problem is with critical sections ( race conditions ) when trying to create the model.

I have tried transaction.atomic and set ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True on db level and yet when I am sending two requests as a race I receive two identical rows.

Is there a way to ensure that Tastypie save function will be atomic ? or any way to ensure that requests will be atomic ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see:

1. The code making the API calls.
2. Any changes you've made to the resources.
3. What sort of stack this is deployed on.

If you happen to be using greenthreads, multiple workers, and/or multiple servers, it's possible the 2 requests are actually being processed out of order.

I strongly recommend changing your code to not perform concurrent actions on a remote resource; wait until one request is done before starting the next.

Comment: Its a redistributed system with several servers. I cant block it to process only one request each time.

Comment: I'd like to help you but don't really have anything to go on. If requests are being processed out of order, there's nothing tastypie can do about that, maybe you could configure your load balancer and/or reverse proxy to send requests to the same server as before on a per user/session basis. To find out for sure if this is the case you could add some logging middleware that adds an X- header with the current timestamp in millisecond or greater precision.

I also don't understand why you can't do one request after another.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in such cases, especially where `save_m2m` is involved, is overriding the `dispatch` method of my `ModelResource`-based class:

```
from django.db import transaction

def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        return super(UsersResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)
```

`dispatch` is called by Django to handle the complete cycle, so either everything succeeds or the transactions get rolled back.